# refactor legacy python code: from u'...' to '...'

Tags: python, unicode, pycharm, automated-refactoring

I have a legacy code project which uses a lot of unicode strings like this: `u'...'`

I want to update the code to use `from __future__ import unicode_literals`

Any automated help from pycharm or an other tool?

**Update**

A simple search+replace does not work, since the code could contain strings like `'fuu'` and I don't want that to be replace to `'fu'`.

Comment: Why remove the `u` prefix at all? It doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: @TimPietzcker why I want to remove the u'...'? Yes, you are right I am not forced to do this. But it looks ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, pycharm has automated find and replace with regex matching.  You could also use a simple tool like `sed`.

**But be forewarned, it is not the case that you can blindly change all modules to include the import:**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

This can cause unintended problems, the issue is not with strings which were `u'unicode'` being changed into `'unicode'`, that part is of no consequence.  The issue is with strings that actually should have been `'bytestrings'` being changed into unicode.

Before you make this global change, you need to ensure that all places where bytestrings are used can really safely be changed to unicode.  Those that can't need to be prefixed as `b'bytestrings'`.

Comment: I updated the question: A simple search+replace does not work, since the code could contain strings like 'fuu' and I don't want that to be replace to 'fu'

Comment: @guettli: if the regex that you wrote to find `u'...'` and replace it with `'...'` replaces `'fuu'` with `'fu'`, then you wrote it wrong ;-). That said, writing a regex to match Python string literals accurately is kind of a PITA, especially if regex isn't one of your main programming languages. In practice you can do a supervised search and replace with an inaccurate regex -- find each match in turn and either replace it or don't once you've looked at it.

Comment: You should also know that this is purely a cosmetic change.  With unicode literals, the strings with u prefix will be parsed all the same (the u is simply ignored, it doesn't cause any error to have them remain there).  The important part is what happens to bytestrings!